# what free fonts can I use in my app for in app purchase?

Tags: fonts

I'm an ios developer and created an app which allows the user to add different texts and reposition them.

I would like to provide my users with a premium feature which is a font pack. I'm looking for a few free fonts that I could embed in my app and require payment for them.

What kind of license am I looking for?
Do you know of any such fonts?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen a free font with a pukka licence where that licence allows the sale of the font. It's free to you; you can't sell it on. You would be profiting from someone else's work which they have provided for free.

Many "free font" sites compound this issue by providing rip-offs of commercial fonts. So you would be profiting from others' work and the rightful recipient of royalties wouldn't be getting anything.

What you **can** do is charge for the ability to use other fonts in your app and then provide (separately) free font packs for it. Again, those fonts would have to have a licence which allowed you to distribute them separately from the original provider, even if you were doing it for nothing.

[StackExchange is not a legal service. This is my opinion and not legal advice. If you want legal advice, pay a lawyer.]

Comment: yeah I thought that might be the case, though I just found this licenses: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL what do you figure from it?

Comment: My reading of that is that the font is free and must remain so, but you can bundle it in software which is paid for (very similar to what I suggested in my answer). The OFL licence must apply to the fonts you supply, so it's not clear whether you have to allow the purchasers to distribute them. [Opinion disclaimer still applies in comments.]

Comment: What is a "pukka license"?

Comment: ["pukka"](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pukka) : genuine, not ersatz; in this case, a good-faith licence from a bona-fide font shop.